# Net Core 5 – How can I force log out from external Oauth2 site?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, oauth-2.0

My net core web app accesses an external site ([www.restream.io](http://www.restream.io)) to get/refresh tokens that can be used in various API calls to that site. If the tokens don’t exist or are invalid, the site requires a login which my app does by opening the external site’s Oauth2 login page by opening this URL:

`https://api.restream.io/login?response_type=code&client_id=[clientid]&redirect_uri=redirectURI]&state=[randomOpaqueToken]`

On completion of a succesful login, the external site closes the login page and redirects back to my web app with a short-lived OAuth2 authorization code which can be then used in an API call to get access and refresh tokens. It does not, however, log the user out so, if the user reopens the site, they are still logged in which is not good from a security aspect and also causes other issues. The site doesn’t have a ‘remember me’ toggle on the login page and the API’s only logout function revokes the tokens which defeats the purpose of the exercise. Is there any way I can force a logout using C#?

Comment: Hm, are you sure user can access site after this process and still get in? The token should be tied to the client (your web app) not the user. But if this is the case, then I'd say does their API offer a logout capability for you to call?

Comment: @Kit - Yes, I’m sure the user is still logged in and there is no API logout capability without revoking the tokens.